# How to chang SSIS project connection manager during deployment

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SSIS project which includes several packages. All those packages used a connection in the project level connection managers.

When the Operation team deploy this SSIS project via ISDeploymentWizard.exe. They need to modify the connection in the deployment script. But I can't find a place to modify it.

Does anyone have thoughts about this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You can't find a place to modify it? You can modify it in BIDS or you can modify it the XML or you can use ISDeploymentWizard.exe to automatically modify it. I'm actually suprised anyone uses that tool as it modifies the source code which is not good practice for change control.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to to modify the connection string, you will need to create an Environment Variable.

It's important to understand the difference between parameters and variables in this context. You set parameters at the package or project level when you create the package or project in SQL Server Data Tools.

Variables on the other hand are part of an environment in SSISDB. Parameters reside in your SQL Server Data Tools project, whereas variables reside in SSISDB.

Check the link below for a walk-through.
http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/ssis-deployment-sql-server-2012

Comment: ISDeploymentWizard is a MS tool which actually alters the packages XML source during deployment. So it actually alters the design time settings of the connection string. IMHO environment level configs are a better idea.